# Как сделать разность дат?

Tags: javascript

Задание: 'Реализуйте функцию getDaysBetweenDates которая принимает на вход две даты и возвращает количество полных дней между ними.

getDaysBetweenDates('1-1-2020', '1-2-2020'); // -> 1

Функция должна корректно работать с объектом Date
getDaysBetweenDates(new Date(2011, 6, 2, 6, 0), new Date(2012, 6, 2, 18, 0)); // -> 366

Функция должна корректно рабоать со значениями в миллисекундах
getDaysBetweenDates(1409796000000, 1409925600000); // -> 1

Если входные параметры - невалидные даты, то функция вовращает NaN:
getDaysBetweenDates('1-1-2020', 'дата'); // -> NaN

Если аргументов меньше 2-х, то функция должна пробросить исключение TypeError
getDaysBetweenDates(null); // -> TypeError'

```
const getDaysBetweenDates = function(a, b) { 

let date1 = new Date(a);
let date2 = new Date(b);
if (arguments.length < 2) {
    throw new TypeError("TypeError");
} else {
    let oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    let time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    let days = 0;
  
    if (time < 0) {
        // days === 0;
    } else {
        days = Math.abs(Math.trunc(time / oneDay));
    }
    return days; 
}};
```

У меня проходит все тесты, кроме

> ✕ возвращает отрицательное число, если первая дата больше второй (2ms)

Comment: Ну если первая дата больше второй, то и миллисекунд в нём будет больше, всё логино. Что именно не так?) Ну можете возвращать абсолютное значение с помощью `Math.abs()`

Comment: Тест не проходит, что тут исправить?

Comment: Там где `if(time < 0)` тоже возвращать `Math.abs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убери условие

```
if (time < 0) {
        days === 0;
      } else {
        days = Math.trunc(time / oneDay);
      }
```

Оставь

```
days = Math.trunc(time / oneDay);
  if (days === -0) days = 0
```